# How to increment input labels dynamically using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am getting some n number of input fields with values from database as below:

```
<span class="" id="row_label">Demo 1</span>
<input type="text" class="input-medium firstrow" name="" id="demo_1" value="Sun" />
<span class="" id="row_label">Demo 2</span>
<input type="text" class="input-medium firstrow" name="" id="demo_2" value="Mon" />
<span class="" id="row_label">Demo 3</span>
<input type="text" class="input-medium firstrow" name="" id="demo_3" value="Tue" />
```

Along with this, am generating some input fields dynamically without values as below.

```
 <span class="" id="row_label">Demo 1</span>
 <input type="text" class="input-medium firstrow" name="" id="demo_4" value="" />
 <span class="" id="row_label">Demo 2</span>
 <input type="text" class="input-medium firstrow" name="" id="demo_5" value="" />
```

Now both type of input fields is having same label. I want to increment the label of second type by looking into the label of first type.

So, I want to increment the label of second type of input fields as Demo 4, Demo 5..

How can I do this???

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique**

Comment: Use the same counter? Or if you want a better guess, provide more code.

Comment: are you generating the empty elements using script or static html

Comment: using script am generating..

Comment: @ Sabof, use the same counter means???

Comment: Add a class `demo` to all the label elements... then you can get the count of labels using `$('label.demo').length` and use it to number the newly added elements

Comment: @ Arun can i have a demo since am a newbie demo helps me to understand well..

Comment: Am able to get the length however, how i can i use it to number the new elements??? any help??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a container element like

```
<div id="container">
    <span class="row_label">Demo 1</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-medium firstrow" name="" id="demo_1" value="Sun" />
    <span class="row_label">Demo 2</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-medium firstrow" name="" id="demo_2" value="Mon" />
    <span class="row_label">Demo 3</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-medium firstrow" name="" id="demo_3" value="Tue" />
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $ct = $('#container'),
        idx = $ct.find('.row_label').length,
        end = idx + 2;
    for (var i = idx + 1; i <= end; i++) {
        $ct.append('<span class="row_label">Demo ' + i + '</span><input type="text" class="input-medium firstrow" name="" id="demo_' + i + '" value="Sun" />')
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b75Yy/)

Comment: I am dynamically creating the second part using parent clone..So, when i click + button on my second part its taking my parent length and incrementing. Is it possible to set my parent length as $('label.demo').length+1; so that when i click on + again it will increment...

Comment: @user3408415 looks like `$('label.demo').length+1` should work

Comment: @user3408415 just edit the jsfiddle I shared to add the relevant code from your end then save it and share the updated url

Comment: Here is the fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/Qg64n/      I have given the second part of creating input and label dynamically..Its not working in demo.However, its working fine in  my website + and - btns..

Comment: @user3408415 it should work fine.. why are you checking whether the button is visible... if it is not visible it won't be clickable right?

Comment: @user3408415 see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qg64n/1/ - there are html and script changes - because id of an element must be unique